# how to index a numeric value to return a string

Tags: c++

I have this enum

```
enum CombatType_t
{
    COMBAT_ICEDAMAGE    = 1 << 9, // 512
    COMBAT_HOLYDAMAGE   = 1 << 10, // 1024
    COMBAT_DEATHDAMAGE  = 1 << 11, // 2048
};
```

Basically, im trying to make a new array/list to be able to index an string by using a specific number to index **CombatType_t**

Something as the following:

```
enum AbsorbType_t
{
    "elementIce" = 512,
    "elementHoly" = 1024,
    "elementDeath" = 2048
}
```

In **Lua**, for example I could make an associative table

```
local t = {
    [512] = "elementIce"; 
}
```

And then, to index i could simply do `t[512]` which returns "elementIce"

How can I do this in C++?

Comment: In C++ the "associative table" is called [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: Additionally, if you do not need the keys held in sort-order, then use [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). For 3 entries -- it doesn't matter from a performance standpoint, but for 3-million it would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, the standard way to make an associative table is `std::map`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
...

   std::map<unsigned, std::string> absorbType = {
      {512, "elementIce"},
      {1024, "elementHoly"},
      {2048, "elementDeath"}
   };

   // Access by index
   std::cout << "512->" << absorbType[512] << std::endl;
```

Comment: I had the feeling it was pretty easy but had no clue how, thank you so much! Glad to learn something new

Comment: It will make no difference here. But maybe we could also consider a `std::unordered_map`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `map` which is the C++ implementation of a dictionary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> m { {512,  "elementIce" }, {1024,  "elementHoly"}, {2048, "elementDeath"}, };

    std::cout<< m[512] << std::endl;
    std::cout<< m[1024] << std::endl;
    std::cout<< m[2048] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `using namespace std` and prefixing with `std::` are somehow redundant ...

Comment: @Sebastian. You are right. I'll leave it there for illustration.